# Js Data table buttons not working when they moves to 2nd row in shrink mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

why the data table icons on the rows not working when shrinks the grid
[as this image icons are in a same row. when click the edit or delete icons they popups modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IssEw.png)

[when shrinks the window size icons are move to second row. it is needed. But icons are not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7mcV.png)

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing it is due to the column width of your UI components.  They can only be dynamic if you add event click handlers. Maybe its to do with the resolution of the symbols. Can you paste the code and show it to us so that we can trouble shoot what is wrong with the code?

Comment: `this.closeFullPageLoader();
        $(document).ready(function() {
          self.dataTable = $("#m_manage_register").DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            order: []
          });
        });`

Comment: <td v-if="checkPermission('api.user.view')" class="zero-td btn-fix-center">
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      class="btn btn-outline-warning m-btn m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill fd-edit-btn"
                      @click="editUser(user.id)"
                    >
                      <i class="fas fa-pen"></i>
                    </button>
                  </td>